# prolog intersection find a common list of four friend and restaurant menu list

Tags: prolog

Hi I want to make a pro-log program. there is four friend they have there own food list they likes. They go to a restaurant.in restaurant it has there own food list in menu. so four friend and restaurant food menu common food show in the program. i try one week but no solution i get ....

```
likes(sam,dahl).
likes(sam,chop_suey).
 likes(sam,pizza).
likes(sam,chips).
likes(sam,curry).


likes(sami,dahl).
 likes(sami,bread).
 likes(sami,pizza).
 likes(sami,egg).
 likes(sami,curry).


likes(samim,dahl).
 likes(samim,bread).
 likes(samim,pizza).
 likes(samim,fruit).
 likes(samim,curry).


 likes(samima,dahl).
 likes(samima,chop_suey).
 likes(samima,pizza).
 likes(samima,bif).
 likes(samima,curry).


resturant(menu,dahl).
resturant(menu,pizza).
resturant(menu,curry).
resturant(menu,bif).
resturant(menu,fruit).
//here i need a function that can intersection sam sami samim and samima food list and also resturant menu food list.
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? How far along did you get? Where are are you stuck? It would also help if you could describe what rule you want to define. As this is written, I'm not sure what kind of query you want to do and what kind of results you expect.

Comment: i use a intersection  but it can not compire 5 rules together .. i need to use a method which can findiut four friend comon food list.. then it can find out common list and resturent menu food list and find which common food in resturent manu .. i am stuck in common food list finding function in prolog

Comment: What you are describing is how you have attempted to solve your problem. But what I'm asking is what you want the end result to look like. What do you want to enter for a query, and what kind of results do you want it to show?

Comment: i want to see result like that 
dahl,curry,pizza in restaurant menu and also common to all four friend......